# how to delete the nth line in a multiline string?

Tags: string-manipulation

How do I delete the $n$th line in a multi-line string.

For example how would I delete the $2$nd line in the following string?

```
multiLineString = "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4";
```

[image]

such that the output is

```
"line 1\nline 3\nline 4"
```

[image]

Comment: `stringDeleteLine[str_, n_] := StringRiffle[Drop[StringSplit[str, "\n"] , {n}] , "\n"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dropLines = StringRiffle @ Delete[ImportString @ #, #2] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
dropLines[multiLineString, {2}]
```

[image]

```
dropLines[multiLineString, {{1}, {3}}]
```

[image]